# How can i reset hidden input value after refreshing page without client side scripting?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

I have a hidden input in my page which has a default value of 0. I am changing the value of this input in my Javascript code.
when i try to refresh the page with ctrl + r, f5 and ctrl + f5, when i use ctrl + r and f5 after refreshing the value of hidden input changes to the last value in my javascript function. but if i use ctrl f5 the value of hidden input becomes the default value which is 0.
I am trying to avoid this situation and i want hidden input returns to the default value after refreshing with all the methods possible. Is this possible without using client side scripting?

Comment: Can you rewrite the form field when it is changed so a refresh will not change to the old default? That IS client-side but before the refresh

Comment: maybe try setting value to empty string <input type=text value="">?

Comment: Short answer, no it is'nt, you'll need to set the value of the hidden input to "0" on pageload with javascript to override the browsers built in "memory" function.

Comment: Using server side Session / Client side cookies are the only available options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is imposible. You need to use javascript to remember it. Maybe you can pass this variable to cookies by javascript.

look here maybe http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html